# How to concate two string on Swig?

Tags: swig-template

I am trying to concate a variable with another string but failed to do so. Till now i tried these things but failed.

```
{{name~' Leon'}} and {{name+' Leon'}}
```

remember i am trying to do it in swig not in twig.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to do it this way?

```
{{ name }} Leon
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIG itself comes with a macro (in `typemaps/fragments.swg`)

```
#define %fragment_name(Name, Type...)     %string_name(Name) "_" {Type}
```

Maybe you can try something similar.